# Where can I find a printer friendly version of the settlers of catan rulebook?

Tags: catan

My copy of Settlers of Catan has been missing the rule book for a while. The Catan official site has [the rule book available for download](http://www.catan.com/gamerules.html), but since it contains a lot of block backgrounds, it's not really printer friendly.

Is there anywhere I can download a printer friendly version of the base game full rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a version of the [original rules](http://bostandjiev.com/Content/_settlers_of_catan/settlers_of_catan-almanac.pdf). The only rules differences (from 4th Edition) would be:

- That now you can move the Robber to the desert.
- Trading and Building are not distinct phases.
- Harbors are now part of the island border.

Comment: That's excellent! I actually have this version of the game, so these were the rules that we'd lost!